# Error : phpinfo() breaks when debug in eclipse pdt

Tags: php

I have installed Xdebug in my eclipse PDT(Mars). When i try to debug a php script contains following code

```
1 <?php
2   phpinfo();
3   print ("Hello world");
4 ?>
```

> After F6(Step Over) from line 2, it will stop and would not proceed to the line 3.
>   However, in the debug window, i can see the debug process is not terminated.
>   In the browser window, the page display "Page not found"

http://localhost/test/test1.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=145637416859820

If i comment out the phpinfo(), the debug works where the browser window will show the "Hellow world" string.

My xdebug is installed without any problem

> This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
>   Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans

I try to catch the exception, howerver, the code will not fall to the catch clause. Every command after phpinfo() will not be execute. This is the reason i suspect the debug breaks at phpinfo()

Appreciate it if anyone can explain this error and provide a solution for it.
Thank you.